# Why does the code below output " dollars" instead of "2 dollars"?

Tags: javascript, regex

```js
const str = 'two dollars for you, 12 dollars for me.';
const re = /\d? dollars/;
console.log(str.match(re)); // Output: Array [ " dollars" ]
```

In my thinking, it should match "2 dollars" instead of " dollars" if the information from [this page](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html) is correct:

> A? : Zero or one A, one if possible (greedy), giving up the character if the engine needs to backtrack (docile)

Comment: It matches "two **dollars**"

Comment: @VLAZ If the default mode is greedy, I think it must look for a number first and find "2 dollars"

Comment: The string is scanned left to right and the first match is returned. The first match is at "two dollars".

Comment: Also, greediness only matters once a match is found, e.g., `dollars.+` will match until the end of the string because the `+` is greedy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP (that is me) fell for the longest match trap as explained [here](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#longest_shortest):

> Sometimes people will try to match a string such as 12 9876 with a regex such as \d+ and expect the engine to return 9876. The + quantifier is greedy, so isn't that the longest match?
>
> This is a misunderstanding. When we talk of greedy or lazy quantifiers providing us the longest or shortest match, it is always in the context of a single match attempt starting at a fixed position in the string.
>
> For the match attempt that starts at the beginning of the string, the longest match is 12, as opposed to the shortest match 1. The string 9876 is never considered in this match attempt as it is not at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1):

It is matching the first instance of  `dollars`, i.e. 'two `dollars`'.
You are correct in your thinking. The next match will be `2 dollars`. You can get every match by adding the global flag, `/\d? dollars/g`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two matches in your string, you're seeing the first one only because you didn't add the "global" flag `g`:

```js
const str = 'two dollars for you, 12 dollars for me.';
//              ^^^^^^^^           ^^^^^^^^^
const re = /\d? dollars/g; // g for global
console.log(str.match(re));
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#advanced_searching_with_flags.

Comment: I am aware of the global flag. What I want to know is the inner working of the regex engine, why the result is as stated above in the case of _no_ global flag.